# Editar um arquivo XLS já criado

Tags: java, xls

Preciso editar um arquivo XLS já criado, porém estou conseguindo apenas se crio um arquivo novo e deleto o antigo, até agora está dando certo porém gostaria de saber se é possível editar o arquivo antigo e não ter que deletar o antigo e criar um novo com o mesmo nome.

```
    String autEdit = request.getParameter("aut");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    File file = new File("C:\\Tratados\\4-600dpi.xls");
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\teste.xls"));
    } catch (BiffException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(autorizacao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\Teste.xls"), workbook);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    int linhas = sheet.getRows();
    int i = 0, x = 0;
    WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(0);
    for (i = x; i < linhas; i++) {
        Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0, i);
        WritableCell a2 = sheet2.getWritableCell(1, i);
        WritableCell a3 = sheet2.getWritableCell(2, i);

        String as1 = a1.getContents();
        String as2 = a2.getContents();
        String as3 = a3.getContents();

        if ("-".equals(as2)){
            Label l = (Label) a2;
            l.setString(autEdit);
            Label ll = (Label) a3;
            ll.setString("Editado");
            linhas = i - 1;

        }
    }
    copy.write();
    file.delete();
    try {
        copy.close();
    } catch (WriteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(autorizacao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui desta forma editar uma planilha já criada:

```
try {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook;
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\teste.xls"))) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {

                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell a1 = row.getCell(1);
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell a2 = row.getCell(2);

                String as1 = a1.getStringCellValue();

                if (as1.equals("-")) {
                    a1.setCellValue("teste");
                    a2.setCellValue("EDITADO");
                    i = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                }
            }
            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\teste.xls"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();
            System.out.println("Arquivo Excel editado com sucesso!");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Arquivo Excel não encontrado!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro na edição do arquivo!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando a biblioteca Apache Poi você pode fazer de uma das seguintes maneiras:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(caminho));
```

OU ainda

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(caminho));
```

Onde `caminho` é uma string com o caminho para o seu arquivo fisico. 
Uma vez que tenha o workbook você pode manipular as planilhas, células entre outros atributos como quiser, da maneira que já está fazendo no trecho de código apresentado.

Esta referência possui um link para uma classe java que exemplifica a leitura de um arquivo existente no item "Reading or modifying an existing file": http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api

Comment: `WorkbookFactory` está dando um erro dizendo que precisaria criar uma classe no pacote, não teria apenas que colocar a importação ou o `WorkbookFactory` não esta incluso na biblioteca JXL que é a que estou usando

Comment: Então, a solução que postei é usando a Apache POI, que considero uma biblioteca melhor e mais atualizada para trabalhar com excel no Java.
Você está usando a JExcelAPI provavelmente por isso está dando erro.

Comment: Ah certo vou tentar baixar essa biblioteca então e testar tua solução? Tu teria por acaso um link para download dessa biblioteca?

Comment: Procure nesta página https://poi.apache.org/download.html
É bem semelhante a que você está usando, encontre exemplos dela neste link: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

isso ai resolve o que precisa

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
File file = new File("C:\\Teste.xls");
FileOutputStream out = null;
XSSFSheet excelSheet = null;
CellStyle style = null;
XSSFFont font = null;
Map<String, Object[]> excelData = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
// verifica se o arquivo existe
if (file.exists()) {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    // vefirifica se planilha existe
    if (workbook.getSheet(excelSheetName) != null) {
        excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(excelSheetName);
    } else {
        excelSheet = workbook.createSheet(excelSheetName);
        addIntoCell(excelData, excelSheet, "0", style);
    }
} else {
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    if (workbook.getSheet(excelSheetName) != null) {
        excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(excelSheetName);
    } else {
        excelSheet = workbook.createSheet(excelSheetName);
       // vefirifica se planilha existe
        addIntoCell(excelData, excelSheet, "0", style);
    }
}
```

Depois feche os stream abertos

Comment: o `XSSFWorkbook` fica dizendo que é necessário criar uma classe para ele no pacote, o `XSSFWorkbook` não é incluso na biblioteca JXL que é a que estou usando?

Comment: Deve ser porque a classe é protegida, veja outra class em sua  lib JXL que seja semelhante e use.