# Automatização Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, automatização

Preciso de alguma forma de automatizar um trabalho recorrente na minha empresa: automaticamente quero pegar tabelas geradas no Excel, extrair informações dela é escrever em uma nova tabela. Sendo que sempre serão geradas novas tabelas para fazer esses cálculos, então periodicamente meu programa precisaria executar essa tarefa. Quero descobrir qual a melhor forma de aprender a fazer isso e para ter um resultado rápido. Quais tecnologias estão disponíveis.

Comment: Você tem conhecimento em alguma linguagem de programação?

Comment: Tenho em Java e C

Comment: Aqui tem uma questão que fiz a um tempo referente ao assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154017/editar-um-arquivo-xls-j%c3%a1-criado

Comment: Se a empresa tiver disponibilidade financeira, eu sugiro fortemente o Alteryx https://www.alteryx.com/

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, R.Santos

Leonardo, vou dar uma analisada no Alteryx e ver se vale a pena, mas no momento estamos dando prioridade a soluções sem custo financeiro.

Obrigado vocês.

Comment: Por que não usa VBA?

Comment: Evert, não conhecia o VBA. Como minha necessidade era procurar em uma pasta arquivos com um dado nome, para gerar outros, pensei que só pudesse resolver com códigos e executáveis. Não é algo que ficaria restrito a uma tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei usar o OpenPyXL, uma biblioteca de python.
Mas me custou muito tempo, pois tenho que aprender python e a usar a biblioteca ao mesmo tempo.